# ElasticSearch JavaAPI RestClient not giving response

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Am using RestClient JavaAPI to fetch documents from elastic search. But am not getting response for my request.

Am forming my request using `QueryBuilder`.

Please find my java code which am using to fetch documents from elastic search

```
private final static String ATTACHMENT = "document_attachment";
private final static String TYPE = "doc";
static long BUFFER_SIZE = 520 * 1024 * 1024;   //  <---- set buffer to 120MB instead of 100MB

public static void main(String args[])
{
    RestClient restClient = null;
    Response contentSearchResponse=null;
    try {

    restClient = RestClient.builder(
                    new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http"),
                    new HttpHost("localhost", 9201, "http")).build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    SearchRequest contentSearchRequest = new SearchRequest(ATTACHMENT); 
    SearchSourceBuilder contentSearchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
    contentSearchRequest.types(TYPE);
    QueryBuilder attachmentQB = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("attachment.content", "activa");
    contentSearchSourceBuilder.query(attachmentQB);
    contentSearchSourceBuilder.size(50);
    contentSearchRequest.source(contentSearchSourceBuilder);
    System.out.println("Request --->"+contentSearchRequest.toString());

    Map<String, String> params = Collections.emptyMap();
    HttpEntity entity = new NStringEntity(contentSearchSourceBuilder.toString(), ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    HttpAsyncResponseConsumerFactory.HeapBufferedResponseConsumerFactory consumerFactory =
            new HttpAsyncResponseConsumerFactory.HeapBufferedResponseConsumerFactory((int) BUFFER_SIZE);

    System.out.println("Printing Entity---->"+entity.toString());

    try {
        contentSearchResponse = restClient.performRequest("GET", "/document_attachment/doc/_search", params, entity, consumerFactory);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } 
    System.out.println("Entity Response --->"+contentSearchResponse.getEntity());
    }
```

Please find the details about my Reqest, Entity & Response that am printing using Sysout.

```
Request --->SearchRequest{searchType=QUERY_THEN_FETCH, indices=[document_attachment], indicesOptions=IndicesOptions[id=38, ignore_unavailable=false, allow_no_indices=true, expand_wildcards_open=true, expand_wildcards_closed=false, allow_aliases_to_multiple_indices=true, forbid_closed_indices=true, ignore_aliases=false], types=[doc], routing='null', preference='null', requestCache=null, scroll=null, maxConcurrentShardRequests=0, batchedReduceSize=512, preFilterShardSize=128, source={"size":50,"query":{"match":{"id":{"query":"87740","operator":"OR","prefix_length":0,"max_expansions":50,"fuzzy_transpositions":true,"lenient":false,"zero_terms_query":"NONE","auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query":true,"boost":1.0}}}}}
Printing Entity---->[Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8,Content-Length: 233,Chunked: false]
Entity Response --->[Content-Length: 929382,Chunked: false]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do get a response which is 929382 bytes long. So you simply need to read the data from the response:

```
String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

Comment: Am parsing `responseBody` to JSONObject if we get single document, but if we get multiple documents from `responseBody`, how can we parse it.?

Comment: I have created separate question for the same.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51043963/handling-multiple-documents-from-elastic-search-using-java-restclient-api