# Is there any difference when applying http_max_content_length setting for elastic clusters for version 7.17.3 and 8.9.0?

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have two elastic clusters one with version 7.17.3 and the other with 8.9.0.

I was having an issue [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51020646/org-apache-http-contenttoolongexception-entity-content-is-too-long-105539255#:~:text=You%20need%20to%20increase%20the,a%20little%20higher%20than%20that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51020646/org-apache-http-contenttoolongexception-entity-content-is-too-long-105539255#:%7E:text=You%20need%20to%20increase%20the,a%20little%20higher%20than%20that).

to which the solution was to increase the cluster setting http_max_content_length.

I have increase it to 200mb on both the clusters.

Also I am using spring-data-elasticsearch 4.4.10, and the same code, but I still get the contenttoolongexception on the cluster with version 7.17.3 and not with 8.9.0.

I did not find anything in the docs about this. Can someone please help here.

Comment: Have you rebooted all nodes in both clusters after adding the settings in configuration files on all nodes ?

Comment: Will check this out, as I don’t have access but when I hit the GET /_cluster/settings?includeDefaults=true. I can see the setting set to 200mb on both @imotov

Comment: what are you trying to do so that a content length of 200mb is not enough?

Comment: I am trying to get around 60k docs for which the size is less than 200 mb but greater than 100mb. I updated the cluster with version 8.9.0 and it worked, buts it’s not the same with version 7.17.3 even though I am using the same client code for both clusters. The only difference is the cluster versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is in the approved answer here in the Update section.

[org.apache.http.ContentTooLongException: entity content is too long [105539255] for the configured buffer limit [104857600]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51020646/org-apache-http-contenttoolongexception-entity-content-is-too-long-105539255)

I did override the buffer size and then it worked.

Also, just an FYI that after doing this applications should undergo a stress testing as it has effect on the heap memory.